# Heating of conductor due to induction?

Tags: thermodynamics, electromagnetic-induction

When I move a charge back and forth from a conductor not touching the conductor, will flow of electron generate heat also?

Back and forth, as conductor is mean position for SHM of charge.

Answer (score 0):

The moving charge will induce the flow of *eddy currents* in the conductor, which could then cause the conductor to warm up through *ohmic heating* if they were sufficiently intense.